How to get chat id using conversation id?
I'm developing a Teams bot app and need to retrieve chat history. I'm planning to use the Graph API endpoint chats/{chat-id}/messages. However, I need to know how to obtain the chat-id for this request. How can I get the chat-id?
public async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, AppState turnState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
      

         string token = turnState.Temp.AuthTokens["graph"];
         var conversationReference = turnContext.Activity.GetConversationReference();


This issue is being tracked here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1865863/how-to-get-chat-id-using-conversation-id. Please follow above thread for further updates. Thank you.
